# How to get the size of a tkinter Button?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

How can I get the size of a button object?

If I do:

```
quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)

_x = quitButton.winfo_width()
_y = quitButton.winfo_height()

print _x, _y
```

It prints `1 1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have not set the size of the button and thus it is 1 by 1.

Comment: Use `quitButton.configure(width = desiredWidth, height = desiredHeight)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size will be 1x1 until it is actually drawn on the screen, since the size is partly controlled by how it is managed (`pack`, `grid`, etc).

You can call self.update() after you've put it on the screen (`pack`, `grid`, etc) to cause it to be drawn. Once drawn, the `winfo_width` and `winfo_height` commands will work.